# How would I build mongodb query object dynamically that matches my ui inputs?

Tags: javascript, mongodb

I have a recipe collection and I want to filter hits that match my ui input data.

My first question would be, how would I store min max values, at the moment I put min, max values in array `[10,20]`, but what if user wants to get hits from 10 and above?

would I store them like this? `[10, "max"]`

Once I have completed filters object, how do I actually turn this object:

```
{
  "protein": [0, "max"],
  "carbs": [20,30],
  "fats": [0, 20],
  "calories": [0, 300],
  "tags": ["vegan", "keto"]
}
```

into something that mongodb understands and can be passed by?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the maximum issue, if the max is 20 why would you store something else? I would go for `{protein: {min: 0, max: 20}, carbs: {min: 20, max: 30}...}`

Comment: @nimrodserok "max" is not 20, "max" means no limits. More importantly, how can to build an actual query object from this?

Comment: Something like [this](https://mongoplayground.net/p/NDQQVt9w8sg)?

Comment: Or is the recipe contains a range the search is with specific values?

Comment: yes, your example is correct, but how do I create that `.find()` object dynamically? What if user hasn't selected any tags, or there is only `$gt`, but no `$lte` on some fields?

Comment: This is not a problem, you build the query dynamically in your js code according to the user input

Comment: The query is a JSON you can easily create like any other JSON in js